# Отобразить значение тега <option> в две строки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть такой html:

```html
<select id="select">
  <option>Сделайте свой выбор</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>Длинное название, которое нельзя сократить</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>Еще одно дллинное название, которое нельзя сократить</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать, чтобы длинные значение отображались в 2 строки? А то портят всю верстку. Значения подтягиваются динамически со стороннего API.

П.С.: На крайний случай, если отобразить в 2 строки невозможно, наверное, подойдет вариант, если у `selecta` появится горизонтальная прокрутка.

Comment: Свойствами `css` - никак, можно только попробовать кастомизировать `select` с помощью замены его хелпером(помещаете туда блок, в него нужные ещё блоки со значениями, прячете свой селект, ловите клик по блоку со значением, меняете `value` у селекта)

Comment: @Klimenkomud не радостная перспектива)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option тут поднимался вопрос

Comment: @Александр да, там есть интересные решения... но мне, наверное, придется делать выпадающее меню. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Отобразить значение тега  в две строки внутри  нельзя, это невозможно**.

От себя порекомендую - уходи от использования нативных селектов, они не стерилизуется нормально, чем раньше начнешь использовать кастомные селекты, тем лучше. Вот пару вариантов:

1. https://select2.org/
2. https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select

Без этого дальше будет... никак )